# Date filter not working in DC JS Charts and Data Tables

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dc.js

I am working on build Charts and Data Tables using DC JS . I have added Date filters separately above code so that I can select Date Ranges. However when I select Date ranges . Everything get's removed from Data Tables and sometimes it only shows data from highest date only.

Any help would be much appreciated !

```
`//Html Code for Date Button
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">DATE<input type="text" class="form-control date_filter txt_bxe_height cstm_txt_width" id="fromdate"> 
    </div></span>
    <div style="margin-left: -4%;" class="col-sm-6"><span style="font-size: 12px;">TO
    <input type="text" class="form-control date_filter txt_bxe_height" id="todate">
     <h5 class="" id="daterange"></h5></span>
    </div> 

//For Data Table
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4 class="titles">PLAN FOR TOMORROW</h4>
    <div class="chart_custom tabel_height">
    <table  class="table table-bordered" id="tabel_plan"></table>
    </div>    
  </div>



----------------------------------------------Javascript Code for both 

 d3.select('#daterange').on('click', function(){    
    var todate=$('#todate').val();
    var fromdate=$('#fromdate').val();     
        exptDimension_recom.filterRange([fromdate,todate]); 
        dc.renderAll();  
       dc.redrawAll();  

    });
    d3.select('#daterange2').on('click', function(){    
    var todate2=$('#todate2').val();
    var fromdate2=$('#fromdate2').val();     
        exptDimension_recom.filterRange([fromdate2,todate2]);   
        dc.renderAll();
         dc.redrawAll();  

tabel_task
        .width(768)
        .height(480)
        .size(10)
        .dimension(exptDimension_task)
        .group(rank2)        
        .columns([function (d) { return  d.Date },
              function (d) { return d["Tasks Performed"] }])
        .sortBy(function (d) { return d.Date })
        .order(d3.descending)`
```

Comment: Oops I think I misread, and the app is not letting me cancel the close vote. If you can create a fiddle demonstrating the problem, that will help. Also we need to see the dimension construction code.

Comment: Again, there simply isn't enough code above for us to help you diagnose this. You haven't posted your crossfilter initialization code. If you can create a fiddle, that would be even better. (Sorry for the confusion with the false duplicate close vote - I've cancelled that.)